# history.forward() does not affect in browser

Tags: javascript, browser

I wrote in the body tag of the jsp page like :

```
onload = "history.forward()"
```

This code is affected in my browser (Internet Explore) but it is not affected in update  version of browser and some Internet Explore.
I also checked "enable javascript" in the mozilla like :

```
Tools ---> Options ---> Content tab --->  Enable Javascript
```

But it is not ok.
I would like to know whether this problem is because of browser version or browser setting. 
How will I do to be affected for the following code :

```
onload = "history.forward()"
```

Comment: What is "some Internet Explorer"? What is "update version of browser"? What version is "my browser (Internet Explorer)"? Be specific and show some effort when you are asking for help.

Comment: My browser is Internet Explore 8. It is ok, my friend browser is also Internet Explore 8, but it is not ok. And then, mozilla 3.6 and mozilla 4.8 is not ok. I tested all version of Internet Explore 6,7,8,9 and Default with the IETester software and all is ok.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I don't know how will I control this.

Comment: Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sCUyD/). It works great in Chrome, IE 9 and in Firefox 12.

Comment: Really, I have to try to be ok in Mozilla and Internet Explorer.

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you with that. Noone uses Firefox 3.6 and 4.8 anymore. And for IE, you should find what is the difference between those IE8s, if it's working on one and not on the other.

Comment: yes, thank you. I will find the difference between these IE8s.

Comment: I know the one difference between those IE8s is that my os is xp and my friend's os is windows 7. I don't know it is about my problem or not about.

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
window.history.forward();
```

Comment: Thank you. It is also not ok.

Comment: Let's start from the beginning:
1 - Is there a page to forward to? Or what are you trying to achive?
2 - Which browser (especially which version) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try `history.go(1)`, this should work.
or `window.history.go(1)`

Comment: Thank you. I tested as you told but it is not ok.

Comment: or add some javascript using jquery and the document.ready function of jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2   /jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.history.forward();
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Use this method. It is working,but it have used jQuery.

Comment: Inluding jQuery for this is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<body onload="onLoad();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) onLoad();">
```

because Firefox uses in-memory caching for entire Web pages, including their JavaScript states, for a single browser session. Going backward and forward between visited pages requires no page loading and the JavaScript states are preserved.

[Click here for your reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching)